# Iterating rows AND columns, in Pandas/Python

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe

so I am trying to iterate rows and columns within a data frame and would like to compare some of the column values to another dataframe's values of identical column names.

So both data frames with about 30 columns where some are objects, some are floats and some are integers.
I would mostly like to compare all of the columns that are integers to another data frame that has 1 row extracted from the data frame, as I would like to compute the similarities of each row in the dataframe 'CB' to the one row in 'ip' and then input that value into the sim column in my dataframe.

(if it's possible to compare  all relevant columns in a way that would be great too)

[Image of dataframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DCjW.png)
In the end I would like to be able to change the sim column value based on the final if statement for each row. This would be best if it was reusable in future like a function as I would like to compare it to multiple "ip's".

Below is an example of one of the variations I tried doing it:

```
for i in range(len(CB)):
current = CB.iloc[i, j]
for j in current:
    ipValue = ip.iloc[0, j]
    if current == ipValue: top += 1
    continue
    if (current == 1) or (ipValue == 1): bottom += 1
    break

if(bottom > 0 ): CB.iloc[i, 30] = top / bottom
```

If anyone could help me with this it would be wonderful, thank you :)

Comment: Hello, did you try using panda's iterrows()? You can refer the end of this answer to know how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60268309/2970272

Comment: I have tried using iterrows, however it may just be that I am not using it properly I will take another look at it

Comment: Also, it would help if you could show us an example to the inputs (both dataframes) and the output) what you expect at the end. That could either be an image (of the DataFrame or an excel if it's easier) or a table in here,

Comment: I've added an image of the data frames and an explanation underneath for the outputs

Comment: Thanks for the images, but I'm sorry, I'm still a little bit confused on what you need as output. You extracted 1 line of CB and that equals IP? And you want to compare that one line with the rest or all lines with everything? If you want to check how close each column is to the others you could use pandas `.corr()` function,

Comment: essentially I am implementing a similarity metric, so the function should look at the 1st  row and compare its column values, to the column values in 'ip' . In this case I am using Jaccards Similarity, where the top = the intersection of the two rows and bottom = union of the 2 rows. I then want to input the result of the intersection/union into the sim column of the row in CB that is being compared to in ip

Comment: This could be useful- [Similarity between 2 dataframe columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50560212/11568368)

Comment: @Vanshika I would need to find similarity between 2 rows more than columns as there are multiple columns I am looking at within each row, however this could be useful for the future